# About compact region that is homeomorphic to a disk in a torus.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $C_1$ be a circle embedded in a standard torus $T$. Let $p$ and $q$ be two points of $C_1$. Assume that $C_2$ is a circle in $T$ distinct from $C_1$ such that $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersect at $p$ and $q$. We orient the two circles. In $C_1$, denote the arc from $p$ to $q$ by $l_1$ and from $q$ to $p$ by $l_2$. In $C_2$, denote the arc from $p$ to $q$ by $l_3$ and from $q$ to $p$ by $l_4$. We obtain three compact regions (1) region bounded by $l_1 \cup l_3$, (2) region bounded by $l_3 \cup l_2$ and (3) region bounded by $l_2 \cup l_4$. Suppose that one of the three regions above is with a hole ,i.e it is not a disk indeed. Then is it possible that one of the two remaining regions (or both of them) is (are) also not homeomorphic to a disk.

Comment: do you want your circles to be smoothy embedded? do you want their intersections to be transverse?  If you allow "tangent" intersections, it is easy to construction examples where the three curves you mention above don't "bound" any compact regions, since they are non-separating.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $C_2$ encircles a side on the torus, while $C_1$ is a simple circle that happens to intersect it. Then regions (1) and (2) are simple collapsible subsets of the interior of $C_1$, while region (3) is the entire torus and so is not a disk.

Switch them around: $C_1$ encircles a side, while $C_2$ is simple. Regions (1) and (3) are still the same, but region (2) is also the entire torus.

For a third example, suppose both $C_1$ and $C_2$ both encircle a side, but one of them is angled so that they cross at the top and bottom. If we choose $l_1, l_3$ are the segments on the inside of the torus and $l_2, l_4$ are on the outside, then (1) and (3) are disks, while (2) is the entire torus. If instead the circles are oriented to make $l_1, l_4$ on the inside of the torus and $l_2, l_3$ on the outside, then regions (1) and (3) are the entire torus and region (2) is a disk.

I've yet to spot a scenario where all three regions are the entire torus, but I would not be surprised if one is possible.

Comment: Thank you so much Charlie and Sinclair. The two circles are smoothly embedded in the torus and that they intersect transversally in two points $p$ and $q$. I see the cases that Sinclair considered. But I really wonder if there is a case where all the three regions are the entire torus. Thank you again

Comment: I think this gives all three regions as the full torus, though I am having trouble picturing it in my mind to be sure: $C_1$ encircles a side. For $C_2$, start at the top point of $C_1$, and have it spiral down on the inside of the torus so that by the time it goes all the way around, it intersects $C_1$ at the bottom point. Then have it spiral up on the outside to get back to the starting point.

Comment: @PaulSinclair that works. If you draw the torus as a square with opposite edges identified in the standard way, then draw the circles you just described in that picture, it is easy to see that the $l_1 \cup l_3$, $l_2 \cup l_4$, and $l_2 \cup l_3$ are all (freely) homotopic to a nontrivial element in homology.

Comment: Ahh, I got your construction. Fine. Now I understand. thank you so much Sinclair and Charlie.

Comment: Sure they do. One goes around the side and the other intersects it almost perdicularly at the top and bottom points.